# Can you use boxes to create a primed variable?

Tags: formatting, boxes

I want to use a symbol to distinguish $\lambda$ in one coordinate set from another $\lambda$ in another set.  Traditionally, we'd use a prime symbol ' to do this (e.g. $\lambda'$).  I tried using this trick in Mathematica in order to keep this symbol from being interpreted as a derivative operation:

```
MakeBoxes[lambdaPrime, StandardForm] := SuperscriptBox["\[Lambda]", "'"];
MakeExpression[SuperscriptBox["\[Lambda]", "'"], StandardForm] := MakeExpression["lambdaPrime", StandardForm];
```

Functionally, this works great.  I used it for all my fancy notations, but the typesetting looks strange.  You get a tiny little ' mark way above the $\lambda$.  Is there a way of accomplishing the same thing with a box that is neither a super or subscript?  (Yes, I know we can use some freakish character that kind of looks like a ', but isn't).  I'm thinking of something like this:

```
MakeBoxes[lambdaPrime, StandardForm] := Box["\[Lambda]", "'"];
MakeExpression[Box["\[Lambda]", "'"], StandardForm] := MakeExpression["lambdaPrime", StandardForm];
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Mathematica was kind enough to tell me.  If you do this:

```
In[] = ToBoxes[λ']
Out[] = SuperscriptBox["\[Lambda]", "\[Prime]", MultilineFunction -> None]
```

You can then make your boxes out of these characters:

```
MakeBoxes[lambdaPrime, StandardForm] := SuperscriptBox["\[Lambda]", "\[Prime]"];
MakeExpression[SuperscriptBox["\[Lambda]", "\[Prime]"], StandardForm] := MakeExpression["lambdaPrime", StandardForm];
```

They work great and look great!